# R - check column index with commas in r

Tags: regex, r, parsing, warnings, gsub

I'd like to make a check of a data frame that I load from outside and in case I found `commas` instead `dots`, I'd like to replace it (easy) but also say in which column I found commas (that's what I don't know how to do)

So I started with something like (of course I'd have much more than two columns to be cheked)

```
dat <- read.table("data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";", dec=".")

#    d1  d2
# 1 0.1 0,2
# 2 0.2 0,4
# 3 0.4 0,3
# 4 0.6 0,1
# 5 0.7 0,5

for (col in colnames(dat)) {
  if (dat[,col].....) { # here the missing control
    dat[,col] <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", data[,col]))
    warnings(sprintf("Replaced commas by dots in column %s", col))
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (any(grepl(",", dat[,col])) )` will check for commas in the current column in the iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `lapply` to loop over the columns and check if any of them contain `","`.

```
lapply(dat, function(x) any(grepl(",", x)))
#    $d1
#[1] FALSE
#
#$d2
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Or `colSums(sapply(dat, grepl, pattern = ",", fixed = TRUE)) > 0`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! these are what I was looking for and I can also apply them for further checks with the same structure!